# Prove: $\cos^3 \frac x3 + \cos^3 \frac{x+2\pi}{3} + \cos^3 \frac{x+4\pi}{3} = \frac{3}{4} \cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve the following identity:
$$\cos^3 \frac x3 + \cos^3 \frac{x+2\pi}{3} + \cos^3 \frac{x+4\pi}{3} = \frac{3}{4} \cos x$$ I applied formulas, $\cos (a+b)$ and $\cos^3 x$ and I arrived at
$$\cos 3x + 2 \cos x - 3 \cos \frac{x}{3}=0 $$

After this I am stuck and any formula I applied, got complicated. Can someone give me an idea as to how I could prove this identity?

Comment: There is an error in the formula you want to prove. The first term should be $\cos^3(x/3)$. The denominator must be shared by all the three phases for the formula to work. With the claim corrected I'm sure you will manage :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you meant $\cos^3 \frac x3 + \cos^3 \frac{x+2\pi}{3} + \cos^3 \frac{x+4\pi}{3} = \frac{3}{4} \cos x$

Comment: Yes. In this case, the identity proof came out immediately. I took this exercise from a book, and in this case, it is certainly a typo. Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth - helpful shortcuts: $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3{\theta} - 3\cos(\theta).$  Also, $(r + s)^3 + (r - s)^3 = 2r^3 + 6rs^2.$

Answer (score 1):

The formula you arrived at is wrong (put $x=\frac {\pi}{2}$ to see that). A correct method would be this:
$$\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$$
So, $$\cos^3 x=\frac {\cos 3x+3\cos x}{4}$$
Now you just have to apply this formula to the given three angles.